# Where to get .xap file in Windows using ionic build?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework for my project. As per ionic build I have used the build command for windows:

```
ionic build windows
```

After the build I get the file structure as below:

[image]

The issue is I'm not able to figure out were do I get the .XAP file inside the platform/windows folder and I'm completely new on Windows build.

Comment: Can you share the output which you get when you run the `ionic build windows` command?

Comment: @Nikola you can check the output result [here](http://pastebin.com/LcZaXujA)

Comment: Can you try this: add the windows phone platform: `ionic platform add wp8`. Build for wp8: `ionic build wp8`, and paste the output that you'll get after these two commands.

Comment: @Nikola the output as per your suggested command is [here](http://pastebin.com/stnPvAmJ)

Comment: As you can see now, at the end of the listing you should have the `CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap` file. I'll outline the steps as an answer so that you can accept it, if of course this proved to be helpful to you.

Comment: @Nikola can we install this xap file on windows phone and on windows 8.1 version. and if we could then  can you help me out for the installation steps without registration of an app.

Comment: i guess you can try, right? I don't have win phone to try. Please update me on how it goes - if you'll encounter some issues, you may want to check the links I added just briefly (about some problems with wp8 not yet fully supported by Ionic team).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just posting this as an answer, to which we came in the comments under the OP's question:

Add the windows phone platform: `ionic platform add wp8`.

Build for wp8: `ionic build wp8`.

The file `CordovaAppProj_Debug_AnyCPU.xap` is the one you're looking for.

However, I would like to turn your attention to these few posts:

- http://blog.vjrantal.net/2015/01/08/experiences-with-ionic-on-windows-phone-8-1/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2015/02/10/running-cordova-apps-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1-using-ionic-angularjs-and-other-frameworks.aspx
- http://appfoundry.be/blog/2014/10/16/ionic-windows-phone

which basically confirm what the official Ionic team says that the platforms wp8 and windows in general are not yet fully supported; but they hope they soon will be.